# How to do input redirection using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input, redirect

I have an input.txt file. In that file, there are a series of pairs such as:

```
interactive 300
cpu 200
disk 400
real-time 500
tty 300
disk 200
```

While making the program I had opened a file called input.txt and used the fstream to read in all of these pairs. Something like

```
infile >> string1 >> int1
```

my question now is, how do I get visual studios to do input redirection with the input.txt file. I've gone and changed all my instances of infile to cin, as I believe i'm supposed to do. I went into Project > Properties > Debugging > Command arguments and typing in :

```
< input.txt
```

But that only works when I run it from within visual Studios. When I compile it, go to the folder where the exe is, place the input file in that folder and run the exe, nothing happens. I just get a cmd window with a blinking _ .

Thanks for the help to anyone that does :)

Answer (score 2):

It is waiting for you to type something.  You have to start it by typing 'yourapp < input.txt' at the command line.  Or you can type in the lines that are now in the file, finish with Ctrl+Z.

Comment: It does seem to be waiting for me to type something in. After I hit enter once, it no longer accepts anything however. I will try what you said and report back.

Comment: Nope, I run the exe (application it says on the info thing in the folder) I type in   J_B < input.txt and after I

Hit enter and it just stays blinking and I can't input anything else. Can't even hit Ctrl Z.

Comment: No idea, you are going to have to post code or debug it.  In VS use Tools + Attach to Process to attach the debugger.  Debug + Break All and look at the Call Stack window to find out what it is doing.

Comment: What code should I post? Again, it works fine if I hit F5 within VS. That does run it and it reads the file. It's when I compile it, go to the folder, and run the exe that I get the CMD prompt that does nothing after I type in J_B < input.txt with the txt file being in that same folder the exe file is in.

Comment: What I can do is type in the input, like the sequence pairs, into the command promp and it WILL pick that up. Does not help me with picking up the file though.

Answer (score 0):

The things you type into command arguments in Visual Studio only work when you run the executable through Visual Studio, using the Run command. Those settings are not saved with the executable at all.

You have to provide the `< input.txt` at a command window. If you'd rather click on an icon to launch the program instead, you can put the command into a batch (`.bat`) file and use a link to the batch file.

Comment: I don't understand. When I run the program, it gives me a command window. Typing in <input.txt does nothing though.
What does work is typing out each pair individually but that is not what the assignment calls for sadly. It calls for it to read the file using input redirection.

Comment: @neojb1989, you get a command window automatically, but it's too late - the program is already running, and the command line was interpreted long before the program was started. All you're doing now is typing `<input.txt` into the program, which doesn't do what you want. It needs to be part of the command line, and I gave you two different ways to do it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. So how do I provide the <input.txt at a command window?

Comment: Worst come to worst i'll just have it use an ifstream to open the file but i'm sure i'll get docked points for it :/

Comment: @neojb1989, in Windows XP use Start/All Programs/Accessories/Command Prompt.